# Is $f(x)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}$, $f:\mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow [0,1]$ bijective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, probability-distributions

This is a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution):

$f(x)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}$, a mapping $f:\mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow [0,1].$

If the domain is in $\mathbb{R}^+$ then it is not bijective, for sure.

Question is, if the domain is $\mathbb{Z}^+$, then does there exist a bijection (one to one correspondence)?

In one sense from the cardinality point of view, there is no bijection, however; from other sense it seems that bijection might exist if each element in codomain gets maps to uniquely one element in its domain.

Where I am confusing, I don't know. Any idea please.

Comment: I don't understand the end of your question. You yourself noted you cannot have a bijection between a countable and an uncountable set.

Comment: If $\lambda $ is fixed then your cardinality argument is the end of the story.

Comment: @ClementC. For instance if I do know the exact numbers which ve been mapped in codomain, and if each element in this set is not mapped more than once to any integer value (in the domain), then can we not say that bijection exists?

Comment: The issue is non-surjectivity: many many elements of [0,1] are missed by this mappjng. For instance if $\lambda$ is rational then all the rationale are missed.

Comment: @kaka The codomain has bigger cardinality, so losing injectivity (which, incidentally, would mean your function is not a bijection anymore, but only a surjection) will not help... you cannot have a surjection from countable to uncountable.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking whether $f$ is injective (one-to-one). The answer is not necessarily. For example, $f(0)=f(1)$ when $\lambda=1$. There are many other choices for $\lambda$ where $f$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: It is NOT injective only if $\lambda^k=(n+k)_{(k)}$ for some $n\ge 0$, $k\ge 1$, which excludes all $\lambda<1$ and corresponds only to a countable set of $\lambda$'s.

Comment: @grand_chat I forgot to mention that $\lambda$ is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, since $[0,1]$ is uncountable, $f$ cannot be a bijection, and in fact cannot be a surjection.  You could directly apply the diagonal argument to describe an element of $[0,1]$ that is not in the image of $f$: take any number whose $n$th decimal digit is different from the $n$th digit of $f(n)$, for each $n$ (and such that none of the digits are $0$ or $9$, to avoid difficulties with non-unique decimal expansions).  More simply, you can notice that as soon as $x$ is sufficiently large (how large it needs to be depends on $\lambda$), $f(x)$ is a decreasing function.  So pick some $N$ such that $f(x)$ is decreasing beyond $x=N$, and choose any $r\in [0,1]$ such that $r>f(N)$ and $r$ is not equal to any of the finitely many values $f(1),f(2),\dots,f(N-1)$.  Such an $r$ can never be a value $f(x)$.